# Problem with dialog boxes being too large for a small laptop screen

Tags: qgis, display

I'm relatively new to the GIS world having just started a course in QGIS.

I've been relatively successfully using QGIS for a couple of weeks on my desktop (large display), but have just switched to my laptop (standard TOSHIBA laptop) for a few weeks due to being on away work.

Since switching to the laptop I'm having problems with the display, in terms of the bottom of dialog boxes and menus not being visible (e.g. the layer properties box). Resultantly I've been unable select 'accept or 'run' etc and progress any further with projects.

Comment: change the resolution of the laptop

Comment: what version of qgis?